Difference between English short stories and short English stories
I'm wondering what is the difference between "English short stories" and "short English stories". I have searched both of them on google and got many results. I think maybe the first one emphasizes on that the short stories are written in English, and the second one emphasizes on that the English stories are short. Am I right?

It’s not necessarily to do with emphasis. The term short story serves as the label for a class of literary work. And English short story means a member of that class of literary works that is written in English or by an English author. It could very naturally appear in a sentence like I prefer English short stories to English poetry, though for me, in Russian lit it’s the poems that are better.
By contrast, the phrase short English story is likely to mean a story in which the characters and settings—and perhaps the style and sensibilities—are English, and such a story that happens to be short.  This phrase is far, far less common and is likely to strike typical native speakers of English as odd.

Right, it can be either, Context will reveal which one.

I was a little confused. In the first use of "English" in your second paragraph, I assume you mean "exclusively relating to the country of England", not the language "English" which is the second usage in the same paragraph.

Yes, @Multihunter, the multiplicity of senses that the word English has was a bit of a challenge in drafting my answer. I  hoped I had found a way to convey my meaning clearly. Anyway, you have understood it correctly.

When encountering the second phrase, there is also the possibility that the writer applied some rule about adjective order (first sentence of Astralbee's answer) without deeper understanding. It can also be a performance error, e.g. the writer positioned the cursor wrongly when inserting the word "English".

According to the 'rule' about the order of adjectives, "short" should come before "English" because an adjective of size should precede an adjective of origin.
However, "short story" is a common two-word noun. It's fine to add other adjectives to describe it, but they should not be inserted into the middle. It would be like saying "a full bright moon" instead of a "bright full moon". If "bright" were a separate adjective, it would follow "full" because it's a quality adjective that typically comes after adjectives indicating size or completeness, but then it breaks the compound noun "full moon".
The other issue with "short English stories" is that, having broken up the noun 'short stories', you could be left wondering if the adjective 'short' describes the English or the story.

you could be left wondering if the adjective 'short' describes the English or the story So, stories that are written using words with a low letter count, or are written by authors of small stature?

The parallel with full bright moon isn’t exactly equivalent, because a full moon is just a moon that is full, so even though full bright moon breaks up the compound full moon, the meaning ends up being the same. A short story isn’t just a story that’s short (indeed, compared to bedtime stories or other everyday stories we tell, they’re usually quite long), so the difference in meaning is clearer. Perhaps a better example would be something like yellow fever (a terrible yellow fever is clear – a yellow terrible fever is completely meaningless).

@JohnGordon I was thinking that a non-native speaker might wonder if "short English" was some abbreviated form of language, or 'short' as in curt or rude.

@JanusBahsJacquet I disagree. I think you're forgetting that when you have a coordinated adjective series the adjectives are comma separated. It would be "a full, bright moon". So, if I saw "a full bright moon" and I didn't know any better I would have to assume that "bright moon" was a noun phrase.

@Astralbee Bright moon is a noun phrase, just like full moon and bright full moon are. A full bright moon would be a bright moon which is full, which is unidiomatic, but perfectly grammatical and still meaningful. A full, bright moon – or indeed a bright, full moon – would be a moon which is both bright and full. In this case, if there is any real difference between the three, it is so minute that it won’t matter in most cases, which is exactly why it differs from the English short story.

@JanusBahsJacquet It's not a recognised noun phrase though, even if its a common adjective-noun combination. And what you're now describing - a moon that is both bright and full is a supermoon.

It’s not a compound noun, no, which full moon is (arguably, at least). But the fact that full moon as a compound is so transparent that it’s semantically identical to the plain noun modified by the adjective in a non-compound manner means that reordering things doesn’t significantly change the meaning of what is said. Short story is also a compound, but its meaning is non-transparent, so if you reorder things, you change the meaning of what you’re actually saying.

@JanusBahsJacquet You're not thinking from the perspective of a language learner. "Full moon" has an idiomatic meaning, even though "full" has multiple meanings as an adjective. Is it a "full" moon because it is not hollow? Is it overloaded with something? No - it means "complete". And not all languages use a word to describe a full moon that translates directly as "full". Arabic has a unique word for the moon in its complete phase, for example. The Japanese term for a full moon means 'complete' but also 'satisfying'.

That is true of every adjectival modifier. A blue car is not blue because it’s sad, and green grass is not green because it’s inexperienced. That doesn’t make those idioms or non-transparent formations. They are straightforward uses of base senses of the adjective to describe a noun – just like full moon is. The fact that other languages may describe the same entity differently is completely irrelevant to the English construction.
